# How to display image of any size in a fixed size 100x100 div?

Tags: html, css, image, size

I want to display image of any size (different width and height) in a fixed size (100px by 100px) div without changing its aspect ratio. I also want to align the image to the center inside the div. I worked on it but image with different width and height (6th) is not coming in center unless I change its aspect ratio.

```
<html>        
    <style>
        .A{
            border:1px dotted black;
            display:inline-block;
        }

       .B{
            border:1px solid black;
            display:inline-block;
            width: 100px;
            height:100px;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        .C{
            border:1px solid black;
            display:inline-block;
            width: 100px;
            height:100px;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
    </style>

    1
    <div class="A"> 
        <img src="man-profile.png">
    </div>

    2
    <div class="B">
        <img src="man-profile.png">
    </div>

    3
    <div class="B">
        <img src="man-profile.png" style="width:100;">
    </div>

    4
    <div class="C">
        <img src="picture.png" style="width:100;">
    </div>

    5
    <div class="C">
        <img src="picture.png" style="height:100;">
    </div>

    6
    <div class="C">
        <img src="picture.png" style="height:100; width:100%">
    </div>
</html>
```

Picture attached below:

[image]

Comment: `img {max-width:100%}`

Comment: With that I get image like (4) in the snapshot. Please see the picture.

Comment: Well, that would "display (an) image of any size (different width and height) in a fixed size (100px by 100px) div without changing its aspect ratio". Try clarifying your question as your intended result is not clear. You can add the code you have now in a Code Snippet so it'll be easier for us to clone it to an answer, also you can generate placeholder images for the sake of demonstration here: https://placeholder.com/ so that no assumptions need to be made about image sizes and aspect ratios, which will prove more useful than a screenshot of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a background image instead. It's the easiest when you need an image to cover up the whole div, and not to change the aspect ratio.

```
element {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-image:url(image.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `max-width` and `max-height` to the `img` tag in CSS.

```css
img {
    display: block;
    max-width:180px;
    max-height:180px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img width="400" height="400" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEEkn.png">
```

The original size of the image is 400x400 pixels, but you can resize it by CSS without any changes in aspect ratio. `<img width="400" height="400" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEEkn.png">`

**Another option**:

If you want to add parent `div` to the image then you can do it something like this:

```css
.container {
    width: 100px;
}

.container img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img width="400" height="400" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEEkn.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use same width and height ie(100x100) for the proportional view.